# select row number for given record id with postgres row_number() function

Tags: postgresql, row-number

Sry, if my question isn't new but i can't find answer. I want to find row number for given id in postgres table.I have the folowing **Postgres** query

```
"SELECT row_number() over (ORDER BY id DESC) FROM 
(SELECT id, row_number() over () FROM user ORDER BY id DESC) AS sub 
WHERE id = ?1"
```

**?1 - user id**

This query always return 1 for any user id, but i need that it return actual record row number. For example, if i have 50 records in my database with ids from 1 to 50 and i execute query with id = 30, i want to retun row_number = 30. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `row_number` function returns the row number in the **query results**. If you query with an id in the where clause (which I am going to assume is a primary or unique key) the value of `row_number` will always be 1. If you want the query to return `30` where `id = 30`, just select `id` instead of `row_number() over ...` .

Comment: Maybe you have any suggestions how i can get expected row number for given id? I understand that my query is incorrect but i can't write correct one(

Comment: There is **no such thing** as a row_number for an id. The row_number does not exist, it is the result of a function and for any given id changed depending on the query. Keep in mind a table is an **unordered** set of rows. Order is imposed by the query - or not.

Answer (score 0):

*If* I followed you correctly, you could just use an aggregate query:

```
select count(*) rn
from user
where id <= ?1
```

This counts how many records have an `id` that is smaller (or equal) to the given parameter.